# Sorting a nested list in python

Tags: python

I have a nested list:

```
a = [[{'aa': 2L}, {}, {'mm': 9L}, {}, {}], [{'aa': 1L}, {}, {'mm': 5L}, {}, {}], [{'aa': 2L}, {}, {'mm': 7L}, {}, {}], [{'aa': 5L}, {}, {'mm': 7L}, {}, {}]]
```

Desired Output:

```
a = [[{'aa': 1L}, {}, {'mm': 5L}, {}, {}], [{'aa': 2L}, {}, {'mm': 7L}, {}, {}], [{'aa': 5L}, {}, {'mm': 7L}, {}, {}], [{'aa': 2L}, {}, {'mm': 9L}, {}, {}]]
```

Output I am getting from a.sort() :

```
a = [[{'aa': 1L}, {}, {'mm': 5L}, {}, {}], [{'aa': 2L}, {}, {'mm': 7L}, {}, {}], [{'aa': 2L}, {}, {'mm': 9L}, {}, {}], [{'aa': 5L}, {}, {'mm': 7L}, {}, {}]]
```

Not desired.

Here I want to sort the list 'a' by considering any one of the keys of child lists.In this case I am using third dictionary and key 'mm'.Right now there is only one key 'mm' there may be multiple key value pairs but I should be able to avoid others and do the sorting on the basis of 'mm' keys value only.

Comment: As far as I see it, both the desired and `a.sort()` output are same(except for some missing whitespaces in desired output!)

Comment: It's unclear what you want to sort by here. I've given general advice, for something more tailored to your situation, edit and clarify a little.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if I got the question correctly, but the answer seems simple to me as below.

Index the third item `[3]` in the key and then re-index the dictionary with key `mm`

```
>>> sorted(a,key=lambda key:key[2]['mm'])
[[{'aa': 1L}, {}, {'mm': 5L}, {}, {}], [{'aa': 2L}, {}, {'mm': 7L}, {}, {}], [{'aa': 5L}, {}, {'mm': 7L}, {}, {}], [{'aa': 2L}, {}, {'mm': 9L}, {}, {}]]
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a list of lists, so you need to sort each sublist if you want to order the sublists.

```
a_sorted = [sorted(sublist) for sublist in a]
```

Obviously, you can run `sorted()` on the list of sorted lists if you want the outer list to be sorted too.

You can pass the `sorted()` builtin a `key` argument - a function which takes the list item and returns the value to sort on. It's a little unclear exactly how you want to sort the list, you could clarify, although with this you should be able to work out a solution.

Your data structure seems a little odd, however. Where you have pairs in the form `{key: value}` you would normally be better off with a tuple: `(key, value)`, or a single, larger dict that contains all of your pairs as keys and values, e.g:

```
a = [{'aa': 2L, 'mm': 7l}, {'aa': 2L, 'mm': 5L}, {'aa': 2L, 'mm': 9L}, {'aa': 2L, 'mm': 3L}]
```

In this case, we can use `sorted(a, key=itemgetter("mm"))` - using [`operator.itemgetter()`](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) - to sort on the value of `'mm'`.

Or, if you need your empty pairs (without using keys to `None`, for example), as tuples:

```
a = [[('aa', 2L), (,), ('mm', 7L), (,), (,)], [('aa', 2L), (,), ('mm', 5L), (,), (,)], [('aa', 2L), (,), ('mm', 9L), (,), (,)], [('aa', 2L), (,), ('mm', 3L), (,), (,)]]
```

Here we can do a similar thing `sorted(a, key=lambda sublist: sublist[2][1])` - we use `lambda` to make a quick function to extract the second item in the third item in the sublist.

If you wanted to keep your data structure as is - if, for example, you plan to expand the dictionaries with more content, then a similar plan would work `sorted(a, key=lambda sublist: sublist[2]["mm"])` - this time using `'mm'` to access in the `dict`.